# squared stage and (4) speaker position

Tags: speakers, stage

I have a theater show with a squared stage (blue). The spectators are sitting on every side of the stage (red squares). And 2 pairs of speakers to be positioned at the corners. The sound will be stereo signal (L/R) and my question is how to couple the speakers..basically where is the left and where is the right since there's no front/back? Is fig 1 better than fig 2? Suggestions?

[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't run stereo in that setup at all.

The closest approximation you would achieve would have only those in the centre of each block being able to hear the image...
You would also only be able to give any sense of directionality to those at the sides. Those sitting top & bottom would have stereo, but it would be reversed.

I'd just run mono.

[image]

Comment: +1 You could add that if there is a compelling reason to run stereo, then I would say it depends on the desired effect. For music playback, I’d go with the first diagram in the question. For localizing sound effects, the second, although it would be primitive.

Comment: It wouldn't work for localising fx. only the 2 sides would be given the correct direction, & mostly they'd probably all be able to hear the 'other' same speaker from the far corner too. I'm assuming this is not a 100ft stage. tbh, a flown rig would be far better, but so would quad output... so I'm guessing they are not options ;-)

Comment: Well, front-back and distance localization is definitely part of human hearing. It wouldn't be great, for certain. I have designed sound for a venue just like this once, and the speakers were flown - it was a black box theater. So flying might be more likely than you might think. Of course I ran that rig in mono.

Comment: I only need music playback..so I'll go with image 1 then..thanks!